# Pad zeroes to single digit to make in minute format

Tags: java, jodatime, date-formatting

My date format is yyyyMMddHHmm and from this dateformat I need to extract year, month, day and add 1259 as HHmm to make a new date,
for which I am using joda date time.

```
 String date = (Integer.toString(orderDate.getYear()) + Integer.toString(orderDate.getMonthOfYear()) + Integer.toString(orderDate.getDayOfMonth()) + "1259");

 orderDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT).withZone(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(date1TimeZone))).parseDateTime(String.valueOf(date));
```

But if the the `orderDate` happens to be 201611051212
the result I am getting is 20161151259 i.e the value of month is 5 which I want as 05. Is there any format specifier for the clock input?

Answer (score 3):

From Joda [docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html): "The count of pattern letters determine the format".

The fix is to use Joda metohds to modify the date so you don't need to invent stuff for manipulating strings.

```
    // your initial date
    DateTime initialDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm").parseDateTime("201611051212");

    // the operation you're trying emulate by adding a string, better to use specialized method
    DateTime resultingDate = initialDate.withTime(12, 59, 0, 0);

    // resulting string representation matches to what you specified as an expected result
    String result = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm").print(resultingDate);
    Assert.assertEquals("201611051259", result);
```